I cannot get the Minverse function to work in VBA, although it works in excel o the identical data
I have created a matrix of numerical data in Excel version 2407 Build 17830.20166 Click-to-Run.
From part of that data, in VBA I've created a square matrix pow. I've written pow back to another location in excel using the same loop I used to assign its values. The Minverse function works just fine on the pow in excel. But when I execute Miverse on pow in VBA, I get "Unable to get the Minverse property of the WorksheetFunction class.'
I have searched on this error and found My MInverse function will not work in VBA.
It suggested I try option base 1. The error message did not change.
It also suggested that the range of the function was incorrect. As I mentioned before, the same data (as best I can tell) in excel works fine with excel's MINVERSE function.
So I declared the parameter inv_pwr as variant instead of as double and then wrote
ReDim inv_pow(r_num - 1, r_num - 1)
inv_pow = WorksheetFunction.MInverse(pow)

It worked! Is this the best way to solve this problem?
Unfortunately, when I tried the same approach with a different set of variables and the function MMULT, it again worked in excel, but I got the same error message in vba that I had before.
Here's my code:
Function data_coef()

    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim r_start As Integer, r_stop As Integer, c_start As Integer, c_stop As Integer, cnum As Integer, rnum As Integer
    Dim m() As Double
    Dim pow() As Double, inv_pow() As Variant, coef() As Variant, vector() As Double
    Dim temp As Double
    
' given an array of data starting at cells(r_start,c_start)
    
    r_start = 5
    c_start = 6
    
' find the last row of non-blank data and calculate the number of data rows (max(rows) = 101)):

    For r = r_start To r_start + 100
        If Sheets("data").Cells(r, 6) = "" Then Exit For
    Next r
    
    r_stop = r - 1
    r_num = r_stop - r_start + 1
    
' find the last column of non-blank data and calculate the number of data columns (max(colums = 21)):

    For c = c_start To c_start + 20
        If Sheets("data").Cells(5, c) = "" Then Exit For
    Next c
    
    c_stop = c - 1
    c_num = c_stop - c_start + 1
    
' Read the data into matrix m:

    ReDim m(1 To r_num, 1 To c_num)
    
    For r = 1 To r_num
        For c = 1 To c_num
            m(r, c) = Sheets("data").Cells(r + r_start - 1, c + c_start - 1)
        Next c
    Next r
    
' Create a sequence of powers of the data values in the second column starting with the one in the second row:

    ReDim pow(r_num - 1, r_num - 1)
    
    For r = 1 To r_num - 1
        For c = 1 To r_num - 1
           pow(r, c) = m(r + 1, 1) ^ (c - 1)
           Sheets("POWER").Cells(r, c) = pow(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r

' Create inverse of matrix pow():

    ReDim inv_pow(r_num - 1, r_num - 1)
    
    inv_pow = WorksheetFunction.MInverse(pow)
    
    For r = 1 To r_num - 1
        For c = 1 To r_num - 1
           pow(r, c) = m(r + 1, 1) ^ (c - 1)
           Sheets("MATVER").Cells(r + 20, c) = inv_pow(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
    
' Calculate coefficients:

    ReDim vector(r_num - 1)
    ReDim coef(r_num - 1)
    
    For r = 1 To r_num - 1
        vector(r) = m(r + 1, 2)
        'MsgBox (vector(r))
    Next r
    
'  THE FOLLOWING CODE CAUSES THE ERROR:

    coef = WorksheetFunction.MMult(pwr, vector)
    
End Function


If pwr is 2-dimensional square array, vector must be a column, not a row. Column in VBA is 2-dimensional array with the second dimension = 1. The result coef should be declared as Variant.

pwr is a 2-D square array. Haven't I defined vector and coef as columns?
ReDim vector(r_num - 1)
ReDim coef(r_num - 1)

It is a row. Column should be: ReDim vector(r_num - 1, 1) if your arrays are 1-based. coeff need not to be redimed.

ReDim vector(r_num - 1, 1)
'ReDim coef(r_num - 1)
For r = 1 To r_num - 1
    vector(r, 1) = m(r + 1, 1)
    'MsgBox (vector(r))
Next r

'  THE FOLLOWIG CODE is still CAUSEing THE ERROR:
coef = WorksheetFunction.MMult(pwr, vector)


coeff is also a column. Remove ReDim coef(r_num - 1) or redim it as a column.

It was hard to see but it was commented out.  Tried both ReDim coef(r_num - 1) and ReDim coef(r_num - 1,1). No luck. Same error.

The problem has to do with how you are constructing your array, possibly complicated by your undeclared variables. And if you are using any row numbers > 32767, you will also have a problem. Suggest you use Option Explicit to check for undeclared variables and also check that that your pow array represents the relevant data rows and columns content.

Your suggestion to use Option Explicit identified simple errors in my code and allowed me to fix my problem. How do I credit you with the fix?

This code works:
Sub safas()
  Dim a As Variant, v As Variant, c As Variant
  a = Range("A1:C1")
  v = Range("E1:E3")
  c = WorksheetFunction.MMult(a, v)
  Debug.Print c(1)
End Sub

In MMult(arg1, arg2), arg1 and arg2 should be
  ReDim arg1(M, N) As Double
  ReDim arg2(N, O) As Double

where M, N, and O are last index numbers. For "safas", they are
  ReDim arg1(0, 2) As Double
  ReDim arg2(2, O) As Double

P. S. There are more working variants:
Sub safas1()
  Dim a As Variant, v As Variant, c As Variant
  a = Array(1, 2, 3)
  v = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array(4, 5, 6))
  c = WorksheetFunction.MMult(a, v)
  Debug.Print c(1)
End Sub

Sub safas2()
  Dim a(), v(), c As Variant
  a = Array(1, 2, 3)
  v = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array(4, 5, 6))
  c = WorksheetFunction.MMult(a, v)
  Debug.Print c(1)
End Sub

Sub safas3()
  Dim pwr() As Double, vector() As Double, c As Variant
  ReDim pwr(0, 2) As Double
  ReDim vector(2, 0) As Double
  c = WorksheetFunction.MMult(pwr, vector)
  Debug.Print c(1)
End Sub

You can select the best one matching your app. The last one defines vector exactly as in your code.

When I ReDim * as double, it says I can't change data types of array elements:            Dim pow() As Double, inv_pow() As Variant, coef() As Variant, vector() As Variant                     ReDim vector(r_num - 1) As Double
ReDim coef(r_num - 1) As Double

Also, neither of my arguments are read directly from an excel worksheet. They are both calculated from data read from the worksheet.

Look at the modified app.

Your code is too complex to follow. This is the idea for 0-based arrays.
Result will always be 1-based.
Sub MMultTest()
   Dim A() As Double, B() As Double
   ReDim A(2, 2), B(2, 0)
   A(0, 0) = 1: A(0, 1) = 3: A(0, 2) = 4
   A(1, 0) = 2: A(1, 1) = 1: A(1, 2) = 2
   A(2, 0) = 3: A(2, 1) = 1: A(2, 2) = 5
   B(0, 0) = 1
   B(1, 0) = 2
   B(2, 0) = 3
   Dim C()
   ReDim C(1 To 3, 1 To 1)   ' this is not necessary
   C = WorksheetFunction.MMult(A, B)
   Debug.Print LBound(C), UBound(C)
End Sub

Following your summary code (assume 0-based arrays):
Sub TestMMult2()
   Dim pwr() As Double, vector() As Double, coef() As Variant
   Dim num As Long
   num = 2
   ReDim pwr(num, num)
   'numbers are assigned to pwr
   pwr(0, 0) = 1.5: pwr(0, 1) = 3.2: pwr(0, 2) = 4.5
   pwr(1, 0) = 2.4: pwr(1, 1) = 1.6: pwr(1, 2) = 2.3
   pwr(2, 0) = 3.5: pwr(2, 1) = 1.4: pwr(2, 2) = 5#
   
   ReDim vector(num, 1 To 1)
   'numbers are assigned to vector
   vector(0, 1) = 1#
   vector(1, 1) = 2#
   vector(2, 1) = 3#
      
   ReDim coef(1 To num + 1, 1 To 1)
   ' THE FOLLOWING CODE WORKS :
   coef = WorksheetFunction.MMult(pwr, vector)
   Debug.Print coef(1, 1)
End Sub


Here 's a simple summary of my code:
' dim pwr() as double, vector() as double, coef as double
' Redim pwr (num, num)  'numbers are assigned to pwr
' Redim vector (num,1)   'numbers are assigned to vector
' Redim coef (num)
'  THE FOLLOWING CODE CAUSES THE ERROR:
coef = WorksheetFunction.MMult(pwr, vector)


I removed the Options base 1 I had set. Your code the runs for me. In my code, I have changed all Dims and ReDims to follow yours. Still no luck for my code.  I must have Options base 1 in my code for the     inv_pow = WorksheetFunction.MInverse(pow) instruction towards the middle of my code to work.

I found several errors in my code when I used option explicit which, when corrected, fixed my problem. Sorry for sending you on a wild goose chase.

The problem has to do with how you are constructing your array, possibly complicated by your undeclared variables. And if you are using any row numbers > 32767, you will also have a problem. Suggest you use Option Explicit to check for undeclared variables and also check that that your pow array represents the relevant data rows and columns content.
It is good practice to always declare your variables. In the VBA GUI, you can enforce this by Tools/Options/Editor/Code Settings and selecting Require Variable Declaration. This will place OPTION EXPLICIT at the top of each inserted module (and you can also manually add this to modules created before you selected this option). This will be extremely useful in catching typos, variables of the incorrect type, etc.
Also, in VBA, it is good practice to declare integers as Long rather than Integer. VBA converts all integer values to type Long, even if they're declared as type Integer. So there's no longer a performance advantage to using Integer variables; in fact, Long variables may be slightly faster because VBA does not have to convert them. And, in referring to worksheet rows, you don't have to worry about rows > 32,767 which is the upper range of an the Integer data type.
If you have a situation where you can be certain that the integer will never exceed 255, you can use the `Byte data type and pick up a bit of efficiency
